# Does knitr not support syntax highlighting in SQL common table expressions?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, rnotebook

`knitr` is documented as supporting syntax highlighting in SQL, however, in the following example only one chunk is highlighted correctly:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document: default
---

```{sql select, eval=FALSE}
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE jimminy > zoinks
```


```{sql with, eval=FALSE}
WITH (
SELECT bar
FROM foo
)
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE jimminy > zoinks
```
````

After some testing I am attributing this to the common table expression (the `WITH` statement).

Is there something simple available to 'turn on' syntax highlighting for both chunks? Anything short of re-structuring the queries to not be CTE?

Comment: That’s a bug. You should file a bug report. In fact, *both* blocks are highlighted incorrectly but it’s true that the second block isn’t highlighted at all. The first is, but its highlighting is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the **rmarkdown** is still using a fairly old version of highlight.js (similar to [rstudio/rmarkdown#907](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/907)). You can choose not to use highlight.js by specifying other values for the `highlight` option, e.g.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document: 
    highlight: tango
---

```{sql select, eval=FALSE}
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE jimminy > zoinks
```


```{sql with, eval=FALSE}
WITH (
SELECT bar
FROM foo
)
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE jimminy > zoinks
```
````